# Teaching in China

Tags: china

my girlfriend just asked me to stay for a couple of years in China, at [Xiangnan University](https://www.xnu.edu.cn/). I would be a visiting professor in some engineering areas.
What do you think about teaching in China? How is it compared with US or Europe?

Comment: "What do you think about teaching in China?" is the very definition of a question that is 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion based', and I have voted to close this as too broad

Comment: Still too broad and opinion-based. VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teaching in China can be a great experience but of course it depends on the individual, have you travelled before to countries in ASIA? The culture chock of staying long term in China can be rather large outside of the bigger cities but the rewards can also be huge to learn about the very rich Culture etc, it is very different than teaching in western countries as the school system here is lagging quite a bit in most places but China is actively working to catch up and better its educational system fast as they are realizing they need skilled youth to bring the country forwards in the future. If you decide to go just make sure you do get the correct VISA etc to avoid problems down the road and make sure you always perform the correct entry and exit procedures and I am sure you will have a great time here.

Comment: What about social security contributions? i'm depositing each month the whole salary i would have as professor

Comment: As a foreigner you dont have to and thus cannot benefit from many of the social security benefits like housing funds and health care, so I would recommend just taking your salary minus the tax and try and negotiate a package with a proper health insurance package included and not contribute to the others as they really does not add value for you as a foreigner but rest assured you really want a proper health insurance pref from Ping An in China with direct billing so you dont have to pay and claim